# Whatapp share from Android webview is not working

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I'm new to Android & I know this is repeatedly answered question & I found lot of conversations on this question but finally same answer. When I tried that answer, it is not working.

I converted my website into Android app, it is working fine !! when I tried to share the link from my webview to whatsapp, it is giving below error

```
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

To fix this, I have seen many suggestions with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. I tried but no luck

My Code:

```
package com.example.abcdefgh;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.Intent;

public
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 WebView mywebView;
 @Override
 protected
 void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
  mywebView.loadUrl("http://www.abcdefgh.com");
  WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 }
 public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public
  boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   if (url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
   mywebView.goBack();
  } else {
   super.onBackPressed();
  }
 }
}
```

I don't know what is the issue, please help me

Comment: You need a code in shouloverrideurl method that will support these schemes. See this page https://www.zidsworld.com/android-development/how-to-fix-unknown-url-scheme-in-android-webview/

Comment: Working fine !!